how can I set the stroke-width of a svg to the same width?
<svg id="wrapper" viewBox="0 0 1000 565.78" height="565.78" width="1000">
<g class="allgroup">
<g role="group" class="allpath">
<g>
<g id="itemid1"><path d="......"></path></g>
<g id="itemid2"><path d="......"></path></g>
....
<g id="itemid20"><path d="......"></path></g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</svg>

Above is the structure of my svg code, the main part is a path wrapped inside a  group, I want to realize that when I click on a certain area of the svg, the stroke-width of this svg is increased to 2.
But I found a problem, this only changes the width of the edges to 2, but the intersection with the other svgs is still 1. If you look closely, you can see that it's a bit finer.
As shown in the picture, area 1 and area 2, when I remove area 2, the stroke-width of the edges of the area is also changed to 2.
My question is how does the svg recognize the edge change and how can I set the stroke-width of a svg to the same width for all of them?
Thanks.



I’m thinking area 2 is in front of area 1, and that part of area 1’s stroke is just hidden behind area 2…

agreed with @PierrePaquette, you could adjust the z depth of the stroke perhaps?

This isn't really answerable without access to the SVG. Consider sharing it over at SVGshare.com - you don't need an account to use it.

This issue is that area 2 is layered above area 1.
There is no such thing as z-index in SVG, so the only ways to fix this are:
Move the clicked area to the bottom of the list so that it gets rendered on top
By this I mean you remove and append the area, from
<g id="itemid1"><path d="......"/></g>
<g id="itemid2"><path d="......"/></g>

to
<g id="itemid2"><path d="......"/></g>
<g id="itemid1" class="active"><path d="......"/></g>

on click.
This is SVG's way of doing z-index.
When the area is no longer to be outlined you don't have to move it back since there's no way to tell visually and it'd be more computationally expensive. But you could if it makes you happy.
Alternatively,
Use a separate layer for the outlines
You could have a layer for all of the base areas and one for the outlines, like so:
<g id="bases">
  <g id="itemid1"><path d="......"/></g>
  <g id="itemid2"><path d="......"/></g>
</g>
<g id="outlines">
  <g id="outlineid1"><path d="......"/></g>
  <g id="outlineid2"><path d="......"/></g>
</g>

You hide all the outlines by default. Then when the first area is clicked, you show the corresponding outline. You might want to disable the pointer events for the outlines layer.
This approach might work better if you want to do animations, like fading the outline in and out.
Side note: If you just have one path within each group you probably can remove the group tags.

Thank you for the detailed answer, I get it, good man.
